# Mac detects external hard disk but does not display contents

Tags: hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive

I have been using my WD external hard disk with my Mac for a long time now. Through OS and other upgrades, there has never been an issue. Lately, when I plugged my exthd in, the disk shows but clicking on it does not display any content. If I leave it for a while (5-10mins), then the folders are displayed but the sub-folders are not displayed. After a while, it just shows that the exthd can't be connected to anymore.

The disk shows on disk utility as normal. The 'First Aid' option is greyed out though.

When I try to view it via Terminal, it shows me the disk but I can't CD into it (permission denied). Info shows that I have read&write.

I have a lot of data on this exthd (it's a 2TB disk and I have about 1TB worth of data on it), hoping someone has a fix.

OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Comment: It sounds like your external HD is dying. Depending on what kind of solution it is, you have a few options. Ideally, it's a single 2T drive, not two 1T RAIDed together. What is the exact make and model of you external drive?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's possible to create an image of the entire disk with the dd command which you can then copy to another hard drive.

This site shows how to do that: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-create-disk-image-on-mac-os-x-with-dd-command/

Comment: Please include the essential elements of the linked material in your answer.